# why javascript let NaN can be overrided in function?

Tags: javascript

*I tested this code in chrome 56*

I just found this weird code.

if I type this code in console `const NaN = '';`

I got this message that I expected. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'NaN' has already been declared at <anonymous>:1:1`

but, if I override NaN keyword in function, like this

`function a(){ const NaN = ''; return NaN; }`

it returns empty string `''`

why javascript let keywords can be overrided in function?

Comment: Probably because of scoping? If `NaN` has been already defined in global scope, your global definition can't shadow it, but a local definition creates a closure and thus a "space" for a new identifier with the same name.

Comment: NaN is a global property, not a keyword.

Comment: The same reason why you can't do `var a = 1; const a = 2;` but you can do `var a = 1; function b() { const a = 2; }`. You can't redefine a `const` variable. Inside the function it becomes a different variable.

Comment: thanks all! :D and I have a another small question. can I use original NaN after redefine NaN in function? (like a `global` keyword in python)

Comment: Yes: `window.NaN` references the global property in a browser context. `global.NaN` in node I suppose

Comment: i would avoid redefining `NaN`. sounds like a code smell if you need to go to `window`/`global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MDN docs:

> **NaN** *is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope.*

It's not rewriteable, you can't assign any other value to it.

**Note** that it's actually possible, but not in the global scope. If you would do it inside a function, you are able then to overwrite it's value and access it, but **only** inside the function scope. Even if you have reassigned values to the `NaN` property inside the function, the global object **won't** be affected.

The same is concerned with e.g. `Infinity`.

Don't be misleaded with the `const` keyword, it's not possible whether with `let` or `var`, but what worths mentioning - using `var` won't throw any errors, but the global object still won't be overwrited though.

```js
(function() {
  const NaN = 'something';
  const Infinity = '5';
  console.log(NaN);
  console.log(Infinity);
})();

console.log(NaN); //hasn't been overwrited
console.log(Infinity); //hasn't been overwrited

//const NaN = ''; --> throws error (has already been declared)
//const Infinity = 5; --> throws error (has already been declared)
```

Answer (score 1):

[From MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN):

> NaN is a property of the global object. The initial value of NaN is
>   Not-A-Number — the same as the value of Number.NaN. In modern
>   browsers, NaN is a non-configurable, non-writable property. Even when
>   this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

The documentation tells that it is non-configurable and non-writable in all modern browser and even if possible you should avoid changing it.